# configuring web.xml from pom

Tags: java, maven

I want to add  to my web.xml based on the build profile but when I try ading a new attribute it shows the following error:

cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'web-app' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

What do I have to do to get my web.xml to recognize this new attribute?

I want to be able to add the  element to the web.xml only based on certain maven build profiles - so how would I comment out the security-constraint element  based on profile.

Comment: Can you show us your pom?

Comment: can you show your web.xml and pom?

Comment: my pom has this profile where I define the new properties<profile>
   <id>prod</id>
   <properties>
    
    <enable.security.start>&lt;!--</enable.security.start>
    <enable.security.end>--&gt;</enable.security.end>

  </profile>  my web.xml contains ${enable.security.start}
  //security constraints
 ${enable.security.end}

Comment: I am trying to comment out the <security-constraint> element based on the profile I am running

Comment: @rrr please add it to the question, not as a comment. It's hard to make out otherwise.

Comment: I had the same error, did you solve it?